# Replicate System.Net.Http method in RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm trying to replicate an example for calling a web API using RestSharp and I'm running into some issues.

Here is the example

```
string apiKey = "my key";
string apiSecret = "my secret";
string requestUri = "https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/Api/GetBalance";
var postData = new
{
    Currency = "DOT"
};

// Create Request
var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
request.RequestUri = new Uri(requestUri);
request.Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(object), postData, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

// Authentication
string requestContentBase64String = string.Empty;
if (request.Content != null)
{
   // Hash content to ensure message integrity
   using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
   {
      requestContentBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(md5.ComputeHash(await request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()));
   }
}

//create random nonce for each request
var nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

//Creating the raw signature string
var signature = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat(apiKey, HttpMethod.Post, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.ToLower()), nonce, requestContentBase64String));
using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(apiSecret)))
{
   request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("amx", string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", apiKey, Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(signature)), nonce));
}


// Send Request
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
   var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
      //{"Success":true,"Error":null,"Data":[{"CurrencyId":2,"Symbol":"DOT","Total":9646.07411016,"Available":9646.07411016,"Unconfirmed":0.0,"HeldForTrades":0.0,"PendingWithdraw":0.0,"Address":"1HEfio1kreDBgj5uCw4VHbEDSgc6YJXfTN","Status":"OK","StatusMessage":null}]}
   }
}
```

I believe the issue I'm having is that the signature variable isn't being created properly. I'm setting the body of the RestSharp request using

```
request.AddJsonBody(request.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { Currency = "DOT" }));
```

To get the body request.content I'm using

```
var body = request.Parameters.Where(p => p.Type == ParameterType.RequestBody).FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString();
```

To get the requestContentBase64String I'm using

```
var requestSignatureBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes);
```

And finally to add the Authorization header I'm using

```
request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"amx {apiKey}:{requestSignatureBase64String}:{nonce}");
```

The response from the server is

```
"Success":false,"Error":"Signature does not match request parameters."
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Rob the response is {"Success":false,"Error":"Signature does not match request parameters."}

Comment: Not at a place to test it out, but I'm pretty sure `AddJsonBody` is expecting an object, and it'll serialize to JSON. Can you try `request.AddJsonBody(new { Currency = "DOT" })` instead  of passing it a string?

Comment: It's still having the same issue, though I the body of the request is easier to look at now.

Comment: In that case, all I can recommend is inspecting the messages sent by the working code, and the broken code, via postman. Then compare the messages and find out what's different. I feel like that'll break down the question into something very specific. For example, your code may be sending the authorization header slightly differently.

Comment: I was able to see the raw request of the correct way and the authorization strings match up.  I wasn't able to get the raw request of the RestSharp way though.  The authorization string for the RestSharp way is correct though.  I think it has to do with how headers are set.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the requests are *identical*? That surely can't be the case if they have different behaviours

Comment: You were correctly pointed out that you need to use `AddJsonBody` with an object, not string. Also, instead of adding the authorisation header manually, you can say `client.Authenticator = new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator("yourtoken", "amx")`.

The rest really needs to be checked against the expected signature. It would actually be very helpful if you could post the expected signature.

Comment: Thank you, the issue was with how I was adding the Authorization.

Comment: hi @patryk - will you please copy and paste the working class to pastebin.com?  (minus api key/secret, of course).  I'm having the exact same issue that you're having.  thanks!

Comment: I have all of this as a project on GitHub, I can link you to that.  The part that deals with this is the PrivateApiRequest class. https://github.com/proletariatpatryk/CryptopiaAPI/blob/master/CryptopiaAPI/Requests/PrivateApiRequest.cs